# WSADMIN jacl Scripting - how get property value

Tags: properties, wsadmin, jacl

in a WSADMIN jacl Script how i can get wsadmin.properties values ? 
for example the "com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile" ?

i already try  with

`puts $com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile`

buts return

`can't read "com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile"`

Answer (score 1):

The values stored in wsadmin.properties are loaded into the JVM, and are stored as System Properties.  You can obtain the values of these properties by working with Java's `java.lang.System` object, and then retrieving the specific property you want:

Here's the JACL code:

```
package require java

set sysprops [java::call System getProperties]
set traceFile [[$sysprops get com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile] toString]

puts "trace file: $traceFile"
```

For anyone interested, here's the Jython equivalent:

```
from java.lang import System as javasystem

sysprops = javasystem.getProperties()
traceFile = sysprops.get('com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceFile')

print "traceFile: " + traceFile
```